# Gorm only get only one records by using Find

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm trying to get all records from my DB,
using Find to get condition records,
here's my code

```
result := map[string]interface{}{}

conn = conn.Table("routeName")
conn = conn.Where("status = ?", 1)
conn = conn.Find(&result).Debug()

fmt.Println(result)
```

As using interface, I only get one row, result as following

```
map[id:1 routeName:FAFA status:1 routeCode:A]
```

I thought it's my interface's problem, so I tried using array as result,
here's antoher define result

```
var result []model.RouteName
```

with this, I got following records

```
{[0    0][0    0]}
```

seen that my records data didn't put into result, to comfire that I did get row records from DB, Using count func to count records and result get 2, so I think that I do get records, but somehow I can't correctly get records value, following is my model

```
type RouteName struct {
    id           int    `gorm:"column:id" json:"id"`
    routeName    string `gorm:"column:routeName" json:"routeName"`
    status       int    `gorm:"column:status" json:"status"`
    routeCode    string `gorm:"column:routeCode" json:"routeCode"`
}

func (RouteName) TableName() string {
    return "routeName"
}
```

I have no idea that why it's work like this, need some advice to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

Gorm cannot access fields in your struct because they are not exported.

> [Exported identifiers](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers)
>
> An identifier may be exported to permit access to it from another package.
> An identifier is exported if both:
>
> - the first character of the identifier's name is a Unicode upper case letter (Unicode class "Lu"); and
> - the identifier is declared in the package block or it is a field name or method name.
>
> All other identifiers are not exported.

### Before

```
type RouteName struct {
id           int    `gorm:"column:id" json:"id"`
routeName    string `gorm:"column:routeName" json:"routeName"`
status       int    `gorm:"column:status" json:"status"`
routeCode    string `gorm:"column:routeCode" json:"routeCode"`
}
```

### After

```
type RouteName struct {
    Id           int    `gorm:"column:id" json:"id"`
    RouteName    string `gorm:"column:routeName" json:"routeName"`
    Status       int    `gorm:"column:status" json:"status"`
    RouteCode    string `gorm:"column:routeCode" json:"routeCode"`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(Edit) Add some description for this answer.

GORM will use [reflection](https://go.dev/pkg/reflect) to map each exported struct tag and
write into the corresponding field.
And unexported fields will be filtered out earlier [here](https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/blob/v1.23.4/schema/schema.go#L157-L165)

---

I think you should try to publicize your struct fields.

```golang
type RouteName struct {
    ID           int    `gorm:"column:id" json:"id"`
    RouteName    string `gorm:"column:routeName" json:"routeName"`
    Status       int    `gorm:"column:status" json:"status"`
    RouteCode    string `gorm:"column:routeCode" json:"routeCode"`
}
```